# Fermionic Wick Theorem

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Assume we are given are fermionic many-particle system with creation operators $c_1^\dagger,c_2^\dagger,...$ acting on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. That is, the $c_i^\dagger$ and their corresponding annihilation operators $c_i=(c_i^\dagger)^\dagger$ act as bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$ and satisfy the CAR relations $$\{c_i,c_j\}=\{c^\dagger_i,c_j^\dagger\}=0\quad\text{and}\quad\{c_i^\dagger,c_j\}=\delta_{ij}\quad\forall i,j$$

In the *bosonic* case, the [Wick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem) can be elegantly written in the form
$$\prod_{j=1}^nc_{i_j}^{\sigma_j}=\sum_{Q\subset\mathbb{N}_n}\langle\prod_{j\in Q}^nc_{i_j}^{\sigma_j}\rangle:\prod_{j\not\in Q}^nc_{i_j}^{\sigma_j}:$$
for any $i_1,...,i_n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n\in\{-1,1\}$, where $c^-_i:=c_i$, $c^+_i:=c^\dagger_i$ for any $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N}_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, $\langle A\rangle:=\langle\Omega\mid A\Omega\rangle$ tenotes the vacuum expectation value and $:\cdots:$ denotes the [Normal ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order). However, for *fermions* this formula has to be modified by attaching an appropriate sign to every of the summands. What is this sign?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a trick to recover the fermionic signs, knowing the bosonic formulas. First, introduce a sufficient number of algebraically independent *"c-numbers"* $\epsilon_k$, that are only required to anti-commute among themselves and with the $c_i$, $c_i^\dagger$ generators. Then, according to the usual sign rules, the products $\epsilon c_i$ and $\epsilon c_j^\dagger$, where $\epsilon$ is any one of the new generators, will obey the bosonic canonical commutation relations with extra anti-commuting factors:
$$
  [\epsilon c_i, \eta c_j^\dagger]
  = -\epsilon \eta \{c_i, c_j^\dagger\}
  = -\epsilon \eta \delta_{ij} 
  = -\epsilon \eta \langle c_i c_j^\dagger \rangle
  = \langle (\epsilon c_i) (\eta c_j^\dagger) \rangle,
$$ for example. The extra intermediate $-$ sign appeared because the $c_i$ and $\eta$ exchanged positions while moving $\eta$ out of the commutator or moving it inside the expectation value. Note that $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ need to be chosen independently, to avoid writing down tautologies like $0=0$ due to the nilpotency $\epsilon^2 = 0$ of the new generators.

So, the bosonic Wick formula still works in the following way
$$
  \prod_{j=1}^n \epsilon_{k_j} c_{i_j}^{\sigma_j}=\sum_{Q\subset\mathbb{N}_n}\langle\prod_{j\in Q}^n \epsilon_{k_j} c_{i_j}^{\sigma_j}\rangle:\prod_{j\not\in Q}^n \epsilon_{k_j} c_{i_j}^{\sigma_j}: ,
$$
where the $\epsilon_{k_j}$ multipliers are all distinct for distinct $j$. I'll leave it as an exercise to obtain the exact sign factor that you were looking for, which you can get by factoring out $\prod_{j=1}^n \epsilon_{k_j}$ from both sides of the above equation.

Comment: This is not just a trick but in fact a universal recipe.  One can prove in various ways (e.g. it is a basic exercise in categorical reasoning) that _any_ fermionic anything --- Berezinian integrals, statements about supergeometry, etc. --- can be recovered from including c-numbers and then only working with bosonic combinations.

Comment: From what I have understood, I coumpute as $[\epsilon c_i, \epsilon c_j^\dagger]=\epsilon c_i\epsilon c_j^\dagger - \epsilon c_j^\dagger\epsilon c_i=\epsilon^2[c_i,c_j^\dagger]=0$. And what is $\eta$?

Comment: Ok, I see now. $\eta$ is "just another $\epsilon$", so it makes sense. I was a bit confused because you wrote $[\epsilon c_i, \epsilon c_j^\dagger]$.

Comment: @RobertRauch, yes and sorry about the typo! Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: I'm now figuring out how to "factor out $\prod_{j=1}^n \epsilon_{k_j}$" from the right hand side, but as far as I see we have not yet explained how the $\epsilon_k$ act on $\mathcal{H}$, so expressions like $\langle \epsilon_kc_j\rangle$ are kind of meaningless so far...

Comment: By the way, can you recommend  any reference on this technique?

Comment: As c-numbers, they can be freely moved in and out of expectation values, $\epsilon \langle {\cdots} \rangle = \langle \epsilon \cdots \rangle$ and $\langle \cdots \epsilon \rangle = \langle {\cdots} \rangle \epsilon$.

Comment: Why? Although we have not yet explained what those *c-numbers* actually are, they are not just complex numbers, because they're required to anticommute among themselves. If I unsterstood you correctly, these $\epsilon_i$ are elements of some extension $A$ of my [CAR C*-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras#The_C.2A-algebra_of_CAR) $A_0$, so in an equation like $\langle\epsilon\cdots\rangle=\epsilon\langle\cdots\rangle$ the l.h.s. should be a complex number, whereas the r.h.s. is an element of $A$. Some hints on how to make your argument rigorous would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. If you are comfortable with constructing algebras/rings from generators and relations, that's really all you need. The hint in talking about the $\epsilon$'s as _c-numbers_ is that you need to extend the _scalars_ of all the algebras you are working with from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$/relations. This makes scalar products valued in the extended scalars instead of simple complex numbers, which should address the question in your last comment.

Comment: Many authors in the physics literature use this technique implicitly. It is sometimes made somewhat more explicit, for instance in mathematical treatments of _supergeometry_. Authors like Berezin, DeWitt, Henneaux & Teitelboim all have books, in a rather hands-on way with specific applications in mind, where you can see this technique of enlarging scalars to include formal anticommuting parameters. There is no limit to the mathematical sophistication with which these things can be stated and more abstract treatments can be found by looking up mathematical references on supergeometry.